# How can I connect to an android device using its hostname instead of its IP?

Tags: networking

I have 4.2 version.
I developed application which implements a webserver on the device. so If I want to connect to the device all I need to do is address its ip: http://192.168.10.x:8080.
I want to replace the IP with a predefined host name, just like 'computer name' in windows: http://android_device:8080.

I found that I need to use Netbios, but I dont know how to activate a service like that.

Is it possible? I dont mind rooting the device.

thanks!
Asaf

Comment: I suppose a dynamic DNS updater can help. See https://play.google.com/store/search?q=dyn+dns

Comment: If you have an answer, I'd appreciate it at https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230644/22600 Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's not an Android specific question, but rather general networking stuff. You need something to resolve the name. As the IP you've named points to a "local network", and if you want to connect from a single computer only, the easiest way to achieve this is making use of the [Hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file) of your computer's OS. On Linux this is `/etc/hosts`, where you can simply add a line like this:

```
192.168.10.15 android_device
```

That's it. Syntax is the same on other OS's, just the location of the file might differ: see [this section of the linked Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29#Location_in_the_file_system) for details.